# Parsing Tab Delim Lines Into Array in C Programming Language

Tags: c, parsing

Given a file (e.g. myfile.txt) with this content (always three lines):

```
 0 2 5 9 10 12
 0 1 0 2 4 1 2 3 4 2 1 4
 2 3 3 -1 4 4 -3 1 2 2 6 1
```

How can we parse the file, such that it is stored 
in arrays, just as if they were hard coded this way:

```
int Line1[] = { 0, 2, 5, 9, 10, 12 };

int Line2[] =    { 0, 1, 0,  2, 4, 1,  2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4 };

double Line3[] = { 2, 3, 3, -1, 4, 4, -3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 1 };
```

**Update**: based on comments by wrang-wrang.
I am currently stuck with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    int ch;
    FILE * fp;
    int i;

    if (arg_count <2) {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", arg_vec[0]);
        exit(1);
    }


    //printf("%s \n\n", arg_vec[i]); // print file name

    if ((fp = fopen(arg_vec[1], "r")) == NULL) { // can't open file

        printf("Can't open %s \n", arg_vec[1]);
        exit(1)
    }



    const unsigned MAX_N=1000;
    int Line1[MAX_N];
    int Line2[MAX_N];
    double Line3[MAX_N];
    unsigned N3=0;


    // Parsing content

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

        if (ch=='\n' || ch=='\r') break;
        ungetc(ch,fp);

        assert(N3<MAX_N);
        fscanf(fp, " %1f", &Line3[N3++]);

        // not sure how to capture line 1 and 2 for 
        // for array Line1 and Line2
     }

         fclose(fp);

         // This fails to print the content the array
         for (int j=0; j <Line3; j++) {
             printf(Line3[j],"\n");
         }    

    return 0;
}
```

In principle I have problem in:

1. Finding ways of how to assign each line to the correct array.
2. Printing out the content of the array (for checking).

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What IO functions do you know about? What looping constructs are you aware of? *We will help you with your homework, but we will *not* do it for you.*

Comment: Are you sure you want three separate arrays?  Wouldn't you be better off with one array with two dimensions?  Are you sure your files all have 3 lines (or more) of data?  Your question has two arrays of int and one of double; your code has three arrays of double; does this matter?  How are you going to tell how many entries there are in each array?  Remember, the arrays are filled with garbage before you start.  Your usage message implies only one file name is accepted; your code accepts an arbitrary number of file names.

Comment: Your code has a variety of issues (outlined by Jonathan Leffler) but it looks to me like the real problem is _you don't know C._ And there's nothing wrong with not knowing C, and we would all love to help you learn it, but we (or most of us) will _not_ just give you code. My answer named a wide variety of functions that can help you, and showed you how to find out what they do, and wrang-wrang's answer has even more functions. I suggest you look up these functions and learn what they do, rather than expecting other people to write your program for you.

Comment: @JL: 1) Yes, I really mean 3 separate arrays. Actually I will finally pass these arrays to another function from a particular linear algebra library. 2) Yes I am sure that the data only contain 3 lines, but the entry of each line can be varied from file to file. 3) I was wrong in my code in declaring Line123, I have corrected it. 4) The code only suppose to accept 1 file. That's why I add condition "if (arg_count <2)"

Comment: @foolishbrat - As to your #4, you are correct - it will only accept one file. However, you are looping over that file. Your code uses a totally extraneous `for()` statement to loop over a list of one filename. If you only have one item, you don't need to loop.

Comment: @CL: Thanks, I have modified the code by removing the extraneous for().

Answer (score 3):

strtok() in `string.h` should get the job done.

Comment: strtok() is rather unsafe in certain situations, and is also going to still leave him stuck with `char *` data.

Comment: +1 as this is the right tool for the job if you know what you are doing and are careful. `strtok_r()` is the reentrant version and can be better to use than plain `strtok()` in most circumstances. There are still issues with these functions, e.g. they modify the string that is being parsed (so make a copy first) and they won't operate on a constant string (again, make a copy first).

Answer (score 1):

1. You're going to need dynamically allocated arrays. Unless you can be *absolutely sure at compile time* of the amount of data you're going to read in (and you can't, or at least shouldn't), you're going to have to use pointers to arrays allocated with `malloc()` and `realloc()`. If you don't know how to do this, read up on memory management in C.
2. You're going to need to convert `char *` (textual) data to numeric types. My personal favorite functions are `strtol()` and `strtod()`, but there are also `atoi()` and `atof()` functions that may be avaliable. However, since we're working with a file stream, here, you may have much better luck with `fscanf()` to do the conversion for you. All of these functions are in the standard library, except `strtod()`, which is C99-specific (so it's in there if you're lucky).

If you don't know how to use any of the functions named there, it should be easy to find manpages for them, either on your system (section 3, e.g. `man 3 malloc`) or the internets ([malloc(3)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html))

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less-usual approach that makes only a single pass over the input bytes.  Scanf will skip whitespace for you, but you don't want it skipping newlines.  As long as your newlines immediately follow the last non-space character, reading a single character and putting it back if it's not a newline will work.  A more robust solution could manually parse the whitespace and put back the first nonspace char before scanf.

Perhaps just copying the nonspace characters into a buffer and using one of the string->number conversions (sscanf, strtol, etc.) would be simpler.

It's more common to read entire lines at once using a library function, then parse the lines.  There's nothing in ANSI C that will do that for you, let alone for arbitrary line length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

const unsigned MAX_N=1000; /* use malloc/realloc if it matters to you */
double Line3[MAX_N];
unsigned N3=0;

unsigned c;
FILE *f;
f=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
while ((c=fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
  if (c=='\n'||c=='\r') break;
  ungetc(c,f);
  assert(N3<MAX_N);
  fscanf(f," %lf",&Line3[N3++]); /* the space means 'skip whitespace' */
} /* Line3 holds N3 items */

/* similar for int except fscanf " %d" */
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it should _always_ matter to you whether or not your code gets buffer overflows. Also, a better way to structure it (in my opinion) is to write a function that takes a file, and returns a (probably `malloc()`ed) array of `int`s. That way, you have less duplicate code.